# Connecting R with Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I need to connect Tableau which was installed in the Windows 7 to R which I am running in Cloudera VM. I had installed `Rserve` Package in R and run these commands in R terminal:

```
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve
```

When I am trying to connect to R in Tableau I am getting following error:

> External Service: An error has occurred during connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6311: No connection could be made because the target  machine actively refused it ExtSvc: Couldn't connect to server

I had tried with `127.0.0.1`, the IP of the VM, and installed Cloudera ODBC drivers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured it out, by adding Rserv.conf file in the root folder with the following lines helped me to get connect with Tableau.

```
remote enable
plaintext enable
```